# Why does this singleton AMD not have access to a different service?

Tags: mvvm, requirejs, single-page-application, durandal

Throughout my app I have references to a singleton AMD called hub.js - defined as follows:

```
// hub.js
define(['services/dataservice'], function (dataservice) {
// list of properties
// dataservice === undefined - why?
}
```

I reference this from other vms by including it like this:

```
define(['durandal/app', 'services/dataservice', 'durandal/plugins/router', 'services/hub' ], function (app, dataservice, router, hub) {
```

But I need access to my dataservice from my hub, as you can see in the first snippet.  References to dataservice from within hub are all `undefined` though, despite using the same exact syntax as the other vms.

If I use a different path than services/dataservice then I get 404 not found, so it seems like the JS sees the file, but isn't loading it into this singleton for some reason.

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a circular reference:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/durandaljs/1BePNd8wk7M

http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#circular